# Choosing a single graphics to use?

Tags: ati, xorg, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

I am running a computer with an AMD APU with integrated graphics. Recently I bought a new graphics card (Radeon HD 7750). While trying to install this, I could not find a proper driver to use.

When using Xorg, I can choose to deactivate the integrated card but Xorg seems to be finicky with AMD cards and it would not let me play an OpenGL game.

When trying the proprietary fglrx driver (from the Software and Updates section), it favours the integrated graphics. Going into the Catalyst Control Centre allowed me to configure it to use the discrete card but the setting would not save (upon restart it would just revert.)

Is it possible to use fglrx with my Radeon card only and not integrated graphics? Any help would be much appreciated.